# Excel: Ranking scores with ties

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ranking

I am looking how to pick a winner, a 2nd and 3rd place out of a list of scores (player names in row 1 and scores in row 2). The difficulty is how to take into account when there are ties. The rules I would like to follow are the following:

1. If only 1 player has a score and all others have 0 then 2nd place and 3rd place should show "-".
2. If two players have the same score, then take the one that is closest to the left hand side (towards column A)

Sofar I have the following:

The winner:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$G$1;MATCH(LARGE($A2:$G2;1);$A2:$G2;0))
```

2nd place:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A2:G2;">"&0)=1;"-";INDEX($A$1:$G$1;MATCH(LARGE($A2:$G2;2);$A2:$G2;0)))
```

Example: Player 1 (250), Player 2 (300), Player 3 (300) => **Winner** Player 2, **2nd place** Player 3

Thanks a lot,

Comment: "furthest to the left hand side" does not make sense. Do you mean furthest **from** the left hand side or closest **to** it?

Comment: Yes you are right this is actually incorrect. I would like it to be closest to the left hand side. thanks

Comment: You are using semicolon in your formula. Is there any specific reason for that ? Also, I found that your formulas (after converting semicolon into comma) are correct and giving value as expected. so what is the exact problem that you are facing ?

Comment: I live in Switzerland, excel format uses semi colon here but it's exactly the same as coma in the US

Comment: formulas work for all except for handling the ties. Example: if player 1 (200) and player 2 (200) will lead to : Winner Player 1, 2nd Player 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is the formula for finding second place in case two players has same highest score -

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A2:H2,">"&0)=1,"-",IF(LARGE($A2:$G2,1)=LARGE($A2:$G2,2),INDEX($A$1:$G$1,MATCH(LARGE($A2:$G2,2),OFFSET(A2,0,MATCH(LARGE($A2:$G2,1),$A2:$G2,0),1,6),0)+MATCH(LARGE($A2:$G2,1),$A2:$G2,0)),INDEX($A$1:$G$1,MATCH(LARGE($A2:$G2,2),A2:G2,0))))
```

Basically, I have added one if formula around your given formula -

1) If two players has same highest score -

```
LARGE($A2:$G2,1)=LARGE($A2:$G2,2)
```

change the range of match formula lookup array. This dynamic range is specified using offset -

```
INDEX($A$1:$G$1;MATCH(LARGE($A2:$G2;2);OFFSET(A2;0;MATCH(LARGE($A2:$G2;1);$A2:$G2;0);1;6);0)+MATCH(LARGE($A2:$G2;1);$A2:$G2;0))
```

2) If winner and second place player does not have same score, original formula is used.

```
INDEX($A$1:$G$1;MATCH(LARGE($A2:$G2;2);A2:G2;0))
```

Limitation of this approach is that it would not be possible to make this formula generic.

For example, for finding third place, there are 4 possible scenarios -

1. Check whether winner, second place and third place has same
   score, then adjust match formula lookup array to start after second
   place score column
2. If winner and third place has same score, then calculate match
   formula lookup array to start after winner score column.
3. If second and third place has same score, then calculate match
   formula lookup array to start after second place score column.
4. Neither score of winner nor second nor third place is same, then
   original formula will be used.

Comment: this works perfectly for the 2nd place, thanks a lot

Comment: It is simple to tie-break when your order of tie-break is left-most person wins. Subtract column(cellArrayReference)*1000000 in both the match array parameter and lookup parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I used array formulas for second and third. So confirm formula with Ctrl-Shft-Enter

Edited

```
Second place = =INDEX(A$1:G$5,1,MATCH(LARGE(IF(A$1:G$1<>$B$5,A$2:G$2,0),1),$A$2:$G$2,0))
```

I am generating a new array by replacing the first place's score to 0 and finding the top person in this new list.

```
Third place =INDEX(A$1:G$5,1,MATCH(LARGE(IF(A$1:G$1<>$B$5,A$2:G$2,0),1),IF(A$1:G$1<>$B$6,A$2:G$2,0),0))
```

Here I am eliminating the top 2 scores.

You can envelop this with the other condition to get "-" when all others are zero.

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot for your solution. Your formula above is for the 3rd place no? What would you use for the 2nd place?

Comment: Sorry, looks like I pasted the same formula for both 2nd and 3rd. Corrected it now. =INDEX(A$1:G$5,1,MATCH(LARGE(IF(A$1:G$1<>$B$5,A$2:G$2,0),1),IF(A$1:G$1<>$B$6,A$2:G$2,0),0))